# How to fix? Xtext grammar stops parsing with 'no viable alternative at input ...' on incorrect input

Tags: antlr, xtext, error-recovery

As an Xtext and Antlr newbie, I'm struggling with getting an error-tolerant Xtext grammar for a very simple subset of a (not JVM related) language I want to parse.

A document in this mini-language could look like this:

```
$c wff |- $.
$c class $.
$c set $.
```

So a sequence of statements surrounded by `$c` and `$.` keywords, with inbetween one or more words that may not contain `$`.  And everything separated by *mandatory* whitespace.

The best I can come up with is the following grammar:

```
grammar mm.ecxt.MMLanguage

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

generate mmLanguage "urn:marnix:mm.exct/MMLanguage"

MMDatabase:
    WS? (statements+=statement WS)* statements+=statement WS?;

statement:
    DOLLAR_C WS (symbols+=MATHSYMBOL WS)+ DOLLAR_DOT;

terminal DOLLAR_C: '$c';
terminal DOLLAR_DOT: '$.';
terminal MATHSYMBOL: 
      ('!'..'#'|'%'..'~')+; /* everything except '$' */

terminal WS : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+;

terminal WORD: ('!'..'~')+;
```

On valid input this grammar works fine.  However, on invalid input, like

```
$c class $.
$c $.
$c set $.
$c x$u $.
```

there is just one error (`no viable alternative at input '$.'`), and after that it looks like parsing just stops: no more errors are detected, and the model just contains the correct statements before the error (here only the `class` statement).

I tried all kinds of variations (using `=>`, with/without `terminal` declarations, enabling backtracking, and more) but all I get is `no viable alternative at input ...`.

**So my question is:** How should I write a grammar for this language so that Antlr does some form of error recovery?  Or is there something else that I'm doing wrong?

From, e.g., http://zarnekow.blogspot.de/2012/11/xtext-corner-7-parser-error-recovery.html I expected that this would work out of the box.  Or is this because I'm not using a Java/C-like grammar based on Xbase?

Comment: Antlr reports the missing symbol in line two (in your statement, the symbols are mandatory). Why do you think it stops parsing?

Comment: @SebastianZarnekow I think it stops parsing because when I test this in a full Eclipse plugin, I only ever get 1 error reported per file, only the first, whatever I do.  Solve that first error, and the second error is reported.  And in a unit test, for the above input {{ParseHelper.parse()}} returns an {{MMDatabase}} whose {{getStatements().size()}} is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to happen here is that in line 2 of your sample input, two tokens are missing according to your grammar: The parser expects a `(symbols+=MATHSYMBOL WS)+` but get `$.`. Antlr will happily try to recover with different strategies, some are working locally and others are working on a per parser rule basis. Antlr will not insert two recovery tokens to finish the rule `statement` but it'll bail out from there. After the statement, a mandatory `WS` is expected but it sees `$.` so it'll bail out again. That's why it appears to not recover at all.
Well all of this is more or less an educated guess.

What will help though is a minor grammar refactoring where you do not make the grammar as strict as it currently is. Some optional tokens will help the parser to recover:

```
MMDatabase:
    WS? (statements+=statement WS?)*;

statement:
    DOLLAR_C WS (symbols+=MATHSYMBOL WS?)* DOLLAR_DOT;
```

Comment: That works, and your guess seems indeed quite educated. Thanks! :-) This
helped me to find another option keeps the strictness, which is to put the
`WS` inside the `MATHSYMBOL`, so that again we have a single missing token
instead of two:
`MMDatabase: WS? (statements+=statement WS)*
statements+=statement WS?; `
as before, but
`statement: DOLLAR_C WS (symbols+=MATHSYMBOL)+ DOLLAR_DOT;`
where    
`terminal MATHSYMBOL: ('!'..'#'|'%'..'~')+ (WS|EOF);`.